# After update my arduino won't compile sketch

Tags: c, compilation, arduino

So i just updated my arduino to and my code doesn't seem to want to compile any more at first i thought it was a problem in my code but after trying a code that use to work it gave the same error which is:

avr-g++: error: missing filename after '-o'

exit status 1
Error compiling.

The platform i am running for my arduino sketches is Arduino 1.6.6. But my update only concerned the plc it self. I have found people having the same problem through the different patches but no concrete solution.

I don't know if this is any-clear and if anyone has a solution to this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the OS? Maybe it-s a problem with the destination directory...

Comment: For the arduino or my cpu ?? where do i find it if its for arduino ??

Comment: You don't have "folders" on arduino... I was speaking about your PC ;) the message says that there is no filename after -o; maybe there are problems with the temporary folder where arduino stores the compiled files, ,maybe there is some other problems with it, maybe.. who knows.. Anyway it's a PC problem, not an arduino board one. So.. What is your OS? and can you post the command which is causing the error (there should be, in the line above, the complete command passed to avr-g++; if not, enable verbose compile ([here](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=115816.0) they say how to do it)

Comment: Thanks a lot I fixed the problem!

Comment: How did you solve it? Your solution can help future readers with your same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved my problem by uninstalling and then reinstalling the Arduino platform. But I have no clue on what is causing this problem that has occured multiple times now.